# Automate BESR 8.5 Restore

Tags: backup, restore, symantec

I have been searching for a way, script, rain dance, to automate the restore of several BESR 8.5 created images (v2i file extension). Does anyone have any experience on how to pull this off?

I have tried Ghost Solution Suite 2.5, but it doesn't seem to work with images that are password protected.

Any help, tool, 3rd party program, etc, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There was a central management console with Version 8.5  It was an option and thought it was included.  This option is free with BESR 2010 and seems to have more features for remote installs

Not sure if it will do what you require or not

Comment: For BESR 8.5 Symantec had a different product called "Backup Exec System Recovery Manager" (BESRM). We have that, and basically it doesn't work for a bare metal install because you need an agent. But since you don't have an OS installed, how can you have one? Chicken before the egg kind of thing. It would be nice if you had something similar to a Ghostcast server, where you can boot device with a light weight agent, and connect to a BESRM session.